# How do I allow the user to invite friends to my app using the 'apprequests' method?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the JavaScript SDK, and the documentation says that I can call a method that will create a dialog allowing the user to select and invite multiple friends to my app. Here is the code I am using:

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Invite your friends to use this app'
}, function(response)
{
    alert(response);
});
```

This code does not work. An error is produced when it is run: "Error: c is null" on line 18 of http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.  It has all of the error processing in it too:

```
        FB.ui
        ( 
            { 
                method : 'apprequests',
                data: '',
                display: 'dialog',
                title  : 'Invite a Friend',
                message: 'I just sent you an invitation to play My Game.',
                filters: ['app_non_users']
            }, function(response)
            {
                if (response && response.request_ids) 
                {
                    jQuery.ajax
                    (
                        {
                            url: 'Invite_Request.php',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: 
                            {
                                'request_id': response.request_ids, 'signed_request': "<?php echo $_SESSION["SR"] ?>"
                            },
                            success: function(data) 
                            {
                                if (data.error) 
                                {
                                    //jQuery("#inviteMessages").html('successful call, but error! ' + data.message);
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    jQuery("#inviteMessages").html('successful request! ' + data.message);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, status, msg) 
                            {
                                //jQuery("#inviteMessages").html('unsuccessful call, error! ' + status + ' ' + msg);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    //jQuery("#inviteMessages").html('Successful request! Request ID = ' + response.request_ids);
                }
                else 
                {
                    //jQuery("#inviteMessages").html('Request failed!');
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code did not work for me. It produced the same error, "c is null". The callback function is never even reached, so the error checking doesn't help.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you're using the same .js file as I am...

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

Comment: That's right. http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js. Also, dialogs 2.0 is enabled in the app settings. I've done quite a bit of research, and it looks like other people experience the same "c is null" issue but there are no solutions.